# Loading Alternative UITabBarController for iPhone5 support

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have to add support for iPhone5 to my app.  Currently the appdelegate uses a nib that is a UITabBarController, and code like this.  Works fine.

```
[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

rootController is an instance of UITabBarController.

So I have created a new nib for iPhone5 and changed the code to...

```
if ([self IsTall])
    rootController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow_5" bundle:nil] autorelease];
else
    rootController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But, the screen is blank with this code, like the nib is not loading.

If I try this I get the correct nibs loading and displaying on the screen but the "MORE" button is not shown and only the first 4 tabs are shown (there are 7 tabs in the tabBarController

```
if ([self IsTall])
    rootController = [[rootController initWithNibName:@"MainWindow_5" bundle:nil] autorelease];
else
    rootController = [[rootController initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[window addSubview:rootController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I also tried...

```
if ([self IsTall])
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainWindow_5" owner:rootController options:nil];
else
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainWindow" owner:rootController options:nil];
```

But this causes a crash on the tab buttons for the nib not declared in the plist under Main 
"nib file base name" setting.

Any help very much greatly appreciated.  This has stumped me for a couple of days now.
Kind Regards
Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Miscellaneous thoughts:

iPhone 5 is iOS 6. Was your app working under iOS 6 before? If not, get it working for iOS 6 *first*. My apps came up blank when linked against iOS 6 even if no other changes were made. That's because view controllers work in a whole different way. So step one is to get the simple of act of launch ironed out for iOS 6. This is particularly true if you are launching into landscape; everything is totally changed in this regard.

Do not add the subview yourself. Just set the window's `rootViewController`. It adds the subview for you.

On the whole you should NOT be loading a different nib in any case. You should be using layout to lay out the same interface in such a way that it doesn't matter whether the screen is tall or not.

Hope something in there will help...

Your second code is totally illegal. Never never never say "init" except in the very same line where you just said "alloc" (except in an initializer, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, app works on iOS6 fine.  Thing is I need to support iO3+ (which is a real pain I know) therefore the auto-layout tools just don't work back that far so dual nibs is the only option as far as I know?  Stand to be corrected.
Yeah I know the init is illegal without alloc, but it showed something!
If I just update my app for iPhone Tall (ie load Default@2x.png) it works, everything is pushed up, but the tabBar buttons don't work.  If I could fix this, then this might be enough??  Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: I didn't say autolayout. I said layout. There are two other kinds of layout besides autolayout, and they go back to iOS 3.

Comment: Yep, that's actually what I'm going to do.  I have figured it out and will keep it to a single layout and move a few things around with code  if I need to for iP5 view.  Thanks for your hints it got me to the right end. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I use

```
+ (BOOL)isPad{
    BOOL result = NO;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)]){
        result = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
    }
    return result;
}

+ (BOOL) isPhone{
    BOOL result = NO;
    static NSString *model;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        model = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    });
    if ([model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"]){
        result = YES;
    }
    return result;
}

+ (BOOL)isWidescreen{
    BOOL result = NO;
    static CGFloat ratio;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
        CGFloat numerator = MAX(size.height, size.width);
        CGFloat denominator = MIN(size.height, size.width);

        ratio = numerator / denominator;
    });

    if (ratio > 1.77 && ratio < 1.78){
        result = YES;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I then have Define statements to make them easier to reach

```
#define IS_IPAD() [StaticContainer isPad]
#define IS_WIDESCREEN() [StaticContainer isWidescreen]
#define IS_IPHONE() [StaticContainer isPhone]
```

I also have a UIViewController category

```
@implementation UIViewController (initHelpers)

- (id) initClassDevice{
    NSString *device = @"";
    if (IS_IPAD()) {
        device = @"iPad";
    }
    else if (IS_WIDESCREEN()){
        device = @"iPhone5";
    }
    else {
        device = @"iPhone";
    }

    NSString *nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",[self class],device];

    self = [self initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];


    return self;

}

@end
```

You will need to have a nib file for each one that has the different items in it. and they need to be connected to everything separately.

Mine currently only separates iphone and ipad so for a view controller i would have

MyMagicViewController.h/MyMagicViewController.m

and for the xib files i would have

MyMagicViewController_iPad.xib, MyMagicViewController_iPhone5.xib and MyMagicViewController_iPhone.xib

the important thing is to match the name of the xib file with the call to initWithNibName:

Also Another thing to think of. is the View you are initializing needs to be the same size as the View it is going into .

```
view.frame = superView.bounds;
```

then it will fit properly

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Much appreciated.
I'm just using a UITabBarController as the class, not subclassing it. I think it's a bad idea to subclass UITabBarController.  I might have to create two UIViewControllers to do it your way.  Food for thought.  There must be an easier way?  Thanks!

Comment: I generally let the first page be a View controller that has no bearing on the app. A navigation controller with a root controller that is the splash screen. then in the splash screen I push my new view controller via the initClassDevice command to get the correct nib.

Comment: Yep, good plan.  Probably a better approach than I have for my current app.  But I will go with a single nib and fiddle the layout in code as needed.  Cheer for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for me adding Default-568h@2x.png to my project resolved it.